# HTML link inside link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have simple table calendar and I have a link inside every td to day detail but I also want to have links to events in td. All my links use jquery modals. 
So how to make link inside link with modals ?

I have this and it's crashing.

```
<td>
<a href="#modal_to_day_element" id="openmodal" data-toggle="modal" >
    #here is for loop 
    <a href="#link_to_event" id="event" data-toggle="modal">
        Event title
    </a>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: You wouldn't do it this way. My guess is #openmodal doesn't have to be an a tag. You should rewrite this to allow that to be a div or span.

Comment: Nesting a tag is not a good idea . It is invalid

Answer (score 0):

It's an invalid format to use nested  tags. Try this way,

**HTML :**

```
<td>
    <ul>
        <a href="#modal_to_day_element" id="openmodal" data-toggle="modal" >
           #here is for loop 
        </a>
        <li>
            <a href="#link_to_event" id="event" data-toggle="modal">
                Event title
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

**CSS :** You can remove the bullets with list items (optional)

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```